# Alternative to collection group query

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a https cloud function which pulls out specific documents from my cloud firestore. The initial collection is 'Message', however then there are various different sub collections. The path for each document I am trying to view is the following `Message/{UserId}/{ChatRoomId}/{UserId_1}`. One variable under each UserId_1 is 'creationTime' and I am trying to query for specific documents that satisfy such creationTime. The problem is I don't know how to solve it as I was told this requires the use of collection group queries, which are currently not available in the firestore. Any alternative suggestion?

What I would be trying to achieve in the end is a comparison of each document's creationTime with the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: As of May, 2019, Cloud Firestore now supports [collection group queries](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).**

As you mentioned, it is not possible at the time of writing to query across collections (the so called "collection group queries" are apparently under development, however).

So the only possibility seems to be a modification of your data model.

You could, for example, duplicate your data and have a collection for each `creationTime` (probably a `Timestamp`), under which you have one document for each triplet `{UserId}/{ChatRoomId}/{UserId_1}`